# html/javascript slideshow does not work

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

i want to have a slideshow in my webpage but my code isnt working.
here is my html:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var slideNumber = 1;
function slide() {
    document.getElementById("slideshow").src = "../images/slideshow/" + slideNumber + ".jpg";
    slideNumber++;
    if (slideNumber == 5) {
        slideNumber = 1;
    }
    setTimeout("slide()",2500);
}
slide();
</script>
<img id="slideshow" src="../images/slideshow/1.jpg" width="500" height="300"/>
</body>
```

Why doesn't it work as expected?

Comment: What shows up in where the slideshow should be? Any error found in the log?

Comment: image 1.jpg is shown.and idk about the log:D

Comment: Is there any DOM you created with id "slideshow"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uff8nydv/

```
var slideNumber = 1;

function slide() {

    document.getElementById("slideshow").src = "../images/slideshow/" + slideNumber + ".jpg";    
    console.log("../images/slideshow/" + slideNumber + ".jpg");

    slideNumber++;

    if (slideNumber == 5) {
        slideNumber = 1;
    }

    setTimeout(slide,500);
}

slide();
```

Also make sure you identifiy `<img>` as `id="slideshow"`

```
<body>
    <img src="../images/slideshow/1.jpg" width="500" height="300" id="slideshow"/>
</body>
```

Comment: i copied your code in my external javascript and also i add an alert so i'm sure that the javascript is connected to my file and i also added the id in my html but it still doesnt work!i'm programing with visual studio(if there is any way to debug with it)i struggled much i really dont know what to do!

Comment: i added     <button onclick="slide()">Try it</button> at the end of the body now as i click on the button the image starts sliding.thank you so much for your help.now, what can i do so the slideshow starts as the page loads?and btw what is that console.log in your code?

Comment: i used onload in body and now the problem is fixed!thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` calls a function `slideit()` that doesn't exist in your code. Chaning it to `slide()` might work better.

Also, the `eval`is unnecessary, and the script chokes because you're trying to access an element `#slideshow` via `getElementById("slideshow")`that doesn't exist in your code.

Edited: fixed it...

```
<body>

  <img id="slideshow" src="../images/slideshow/1.jpg" width="500" height="300"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var slideNumber = 1;
    function slide() {
        document.getElementById("slideshow").src = "../images/slideshow/" + slideNumber + ".jpg";
        slideNumber++;
        if (slideNumber == 5) {
            slideNumber = 1;
        }
        setTimeout("slide()",1000);
    }
    slide();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Also, the variable slideNumber will never be equal to 5.

Comment: @danielaKay:yeah!right!i fixed it but nth changed also i took it out of the if:)thank you

Comment: @Alfabravo:oh yeah!anyways the function does nth, but also!what should i do if i want the slideshow keep running all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the id="slideshow" to

```
  img src="../images/slideshow/1.jpg" id="slideshow" width="500" height="300"
```

in order to change the image.